# Some of the entries of the glossary do not get printed

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In my thesis, for the printing the glossary, I have put the command `\printglossaries`. Before that I have put `\input{acronyms.tex}` command since I have created a separate file to put the list of acronyms.

In that file, I have 17 entries. But when the PDF is generated for my document, only 13 out of 17 entries are getting printed. Other 4 is missing. Are there any limits for the number of acronyms I can put in a document? I am using the report document class.

Why is this? How can I overcome this issue?

**EDIT**

For adding the acronyms I referred the article [Glossary and acronyms in LaTeX](https://philmikejones.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/glossary-acronyms-latex/)

Comment: Did you use all entries in your document? Sounds like you just print the ones you used.

Comment: `\glsaddall` will provide any entry! There's a clear warning in the manual of `glossaries` not to define acronyms or glossary entries in the main body.

Comment: The package provides special commands to load entries from external files. Why aren't you using those?

Comment: @Rico I have used all them

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have put all the acronyms in a seperate file, not in the main file.  BTW what is `\glsaddall`

Comment: @cfr Can u pls provide some such commands and how to use them

Comment: If you post a Minimal Working Example (MWE) it would make sense to show you how to do it. If you'd rather not do that, please see the related questions on the right and the package documentation (which is extremely thorough). It doesn't make sense to repeat generic explanations here when so much exists already and, without an MWE, generic explanations are all anybody could give you.

Comment: @vigamage: Follow cfr's instructions please

Comment: @vigamage: Any news on this?

Comment: Sorry I could not give u any updates on this since I had to submit my thesis. The sad news is I wrote all of the acronyms manually. :(

Comment: @vigamage: If you would have provided a MWE right from the start manually writting  would not have been necessary.  :-(